# Running unmanaged C++ function on client-side ASP .Net C#

Tags: asp.net, c++, activex

Some functions in a legacy C++ Win32 application needs to be run on client-side in a new ASP .NET C# MVC Web application. Functions such as accessing client side shared memory.

I was wondering what is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by implementing an ActiveX component, although I don't think anyone would recommend it.  There is really no other way to download/install client-side native code via a web site.  Note that this limits you to web browsers that support ActiveX controls, and it will only run on the platform for which the native code is compiled/linked.

Another possibility is to get the user to install a native service on the client side, and then access it via some sort of IPC interface.